# Auto-Login to IE url with Batch

Tags: batch-file, autologin

I'm trying to write a Batch script to open a url and auto feed my username, tab down, auto feed my password, and hit enter. I'm fairly new to Batch, os I can work with directories, and that's about it, so the calling of the url is no problem, but I'm having issues with feeding. A different question suggested the following, which wouldn't call the link that's sitting on the desktop.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("http://url.url", 1, false)

WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "username"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

This didn't work, it just threw errors saying that it isn't a recognized internal or external Batch command.

Thoughts?

EDIT: Rostok's answer worked (Thank you!), and I even added a little snippet at the end to navigate and choose an option to load the rest of the page.

```
WScript.Sleep(2000);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
```

This stuff makes sense to me now, but everything around the similar code block from the answer still looks foreign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run WScript from the command line create autologin.wsf file with this contents:

```
<package>
<job id="js">
<script language="JScript">
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("http://url.url", 1, false)
WshShell.AppActivate("your app title");
WScript.Sleep(2000);
WshShell.SendKeys("username");
WScript.Sleep(1000);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(1000);
WshShell.SendKeys("password");
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(1000);
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
</script>
</job>
</package>
```

Then just run it.

Alternatively you can just use Autohotkeys